# Function Returning NSString Always Returns nil in iOS 4.2 SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios-4.2

The following code, while not necessarily pretty, worked absolutely fine in iOS 4.1 (returned an NSString with formatted HTML with the passed URL).  In iOS 4.2.1, however, the function always returns nil if using stringWithFormat.  NSLog shows the contents of embedHTML are correct, but the value of *html is always nil.

Any help is appreciated.

```
....
NSString *html = [self getHTML:urlString1];
....

- (NSString *)getHTML:(NSString *) url {

NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"111\" height=\"116f\"></embed>\
</body></html>", url];

NSLog(@"Log: %@", embedHTML);

return embedHTML;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put quotes around each split line. You shouldn't need the backslash.

This question is similar, for C++, but I think the same rules apply to Objective C

[Splitting C++ Strings Onto Multiple Lines (Code Syntax, Not Parsing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859157/splitting-c-strings-onto-multiple-lines-code-syntax-not-parsing)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Turns out there was actually an issue in the string I was attempting to insert that was throwing everything off. To make a short story long, it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head>\
                       <style type=\"text/css\">\
                       body {\
                       background-color: transparent;\
                       color: white;\
                       </style>\
                       </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                       <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                       width=\"111\" height=\"116f\"></embed>\
                       </body></html>", urlString1];
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting is that even if I put the code inline vs a function, the result is still nil...

Comment: Stranger and stranger...  Still *html is nil -- even inline.

Comment: Even a line as simple as this returns nil: NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test String: %@", @"iPhone"];

Comment: Maybe there can be a problem in xcode or iOS SDK. Try reinstalling them.

Comment: Yeah -- I tried just rerunning the installer, but no dice.  However, I just ran it on another system, and it worked.  Looks like a complete uninstall and reinstall is in order.  I'll let you know.

Comment: God, I hate that.  Total uninstall/reinstall took care of it.  Thanks for all your time.